# Unable to get bool settings from class

Tags: c#

Player class with boolean settings which I want to get in another class and change

```
public Dictionary<string, bool>? Settings
{
    get
    {
        Dictionary<string, bool> settings = null!;

        foreach (var property in GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(bool)))
        {
            settings?.Add(property.Name, (bool) property.GetValue(this, null)!);
        }
        
        return settings;
    }
}
```

p.s. f i add log to foreach then I will see the variable and its state

if this is important, then I use the latest version of the counterstrikesharp API, but the problem here is most likely not in the API

```
private void CreateMenu(CCSPlayerController? player)
        {
            if (player == null) return;

            if (!_players.TryGetValue(player.SteamID.ToString(), out var user)) return;

            var title = "RES";
            user!.Menu = Config.UseCenterHtmlMenu ? new CenterHtmlMenu(title) : new ChatMenu(title);

            if (user.Menu == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("user.Menu == null");
                return;
            }
            _logUtils.Log(user.Settings?.Count.ToString()); // empty log
            
            foreach (var (feature, state) in user.Settings!) // user.Settings empty too
            {
                _logUtils.Log("TEST 6");
                var featureState = state switch
                {
                    true => "[ВКЛ]",
                    false => "[ВЫКЛ]"
                };
                
                user.Menu.AddMenuOption(
                    feature + ($"[{featureState}]"),
                    (controller, _) =>
                    {
                        var returnState = featureState;
                        
                        player.PrintToChat($"{feature}: {(returnState == featureState ? "[ВКЛ]" : "[ВЫКЛ]")}");
                        
                        if (Config.ReOpenMenuAfterItemClick)
                            CreateMenu(controller);
                    });
            }

            if (Config.UseCenterHtmlMenu)
                MenuManager.OpenCenterHtmlMenu(this, player, (CenterHtmlMenu)user.Menu);
            else
                MenuManager.OpenChatMenu(player, (ChatMenu)user.Menu);
        }
```

I marked problem areas with comments

I logged and debugged, but I can’t understand what the problem is

Comment: Your settings are always `null` . You never create them. Is that intended?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I fill these parameters with settings from the database when a player connects and put them in a list

Comment: But you never fill anything. `Dictionary<string, bool> settings = null!;` doesn't create a new dictionary. You need at least one `new` to create an instance in C#.

Comment: Your `foreach` does nothing besides looping. `settings` is null, so `.Add()` is never called, and finally `settings` (which is still null) is returned.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel when a player connects, I look at his settings in the database and then transfer them to the player class and add them to memory. the player class is filled with these bool parameters and I expect that I can get a list of them directly from the player class with this get method

Comment: Okay, riddle me this: how do you expect `settings` to contain anything if it's always null?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel thx, with new() fixed

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel [link](https://ibb.co/NLxYfKM)